# Mysql workbench on mac os x does not display result grid

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

Workbench Screenshot
[image]

When I run queries in workbench the results grid does not appear. The log suggests that the action is successful but I do not get the table of results.

I can drag up from the Action Output and see an empty panel display.

Workbench with empty grey panel
[image: Workbench with empty grey panel]

I am using MySQL workbench 6.3.10 on Mac OS X 10.13.2 (17C88). I have attempted reinstalling by deleting all the references I could find to Workbench under ~/Library but this has not resolved the issue.

Does anyone know how I can get the results panel working again?

Comment: If you want reset all WB setting you should delete (or rename) dir ~/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench. You can also try reboot your machine after Wb upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try rebooting after the new installation? I had the same issue but an updated version and restart solved it.

Comment: I certainly thought I had rebooted. Hopefully that is it resolved. Thanks.